# Multiple wildcard bounds

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Suppose that I have the following class:

```
public class Either<A, B> {
    public Object get();
}
```

`Either` is a type that stores one object of either type A or B.  `get()` retrieves that one object.

The question is whether or not it is possible to use generics to alter the method signature of `get()` so that the type returned is not just `Object`, but any common supertype of A and B.  For example, an `Either<Integer, Long>` can have `get()` return `Number`, an `Either<Deque<T>, Set<T>>` can have `get()` return `Iterable<T>` or `Collection<T>`, and so on.  (Obviously, an `Either<Foo,Foo>` should have `get()` return `Foo`).

If this is at all possible, if I had `Either<List<A>, List<B>>`, what is the most specific type `get()` can return?  Is it raw `List`, wildcard `List<?>`, or something else entirely?

Comment: Did anyone actually address the question about `Either<List<A>, List<B>>`? Anyway it would need to be `List<?>`.

Answer (score 2):

Java inference do have something similar, we can do

```
public static <C, A extends C, B extends C> C get(Either<A,B> e)
{   return (C)e.get();    }

inference:

    A=Integer, B=Long    ==>    C=Number

    A=List<Integer>, B=List<Long>      ==>   C=List<? extends Number>

usage:

    Either<Integer, Long> x = ...;
    get(x); // the return type is Number
```

However there's probably no way to turn it into an instance method. We would need to write

```
public class Either<A,B>

    public <C super A|B> C get() { ... }

or simply

    public A|B get(){ ... }
```

which is not supported in Java

Answer (score 1):

Why not define an abstract class C, containing as much logic common to A and B as you deem necessary, and refer to that in your Either class:

```
public class Either<C> {
    public C get();
}
```

That doesn't seem like much of an answer, but since Java erases your type information anyway when compiling (that it to say, your compiled code sees only `Object` instead of an `A` or a `B`), then you are in the best position to define what should be retained in an explicit common class.

Comment: A and B may be unrelated classes that I cannot modify, such as `Integer` and `Long` above; abstraction to a common superclass may not be possible.

Comment: you can maybe wrap these classes, much like the Hadoop framework does with IntWritable etc. The wrappers can then derive from a common, abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible: your `Either<A,B>` class makes an assumption about a generic third type (let's call it `C`), which both A and B would extend: while it is possible to write something like `public class Either<A extends MyNonFinalClass, B extends MyNonFinalClass> {}`, Java doesn't allow forward-referencing a generic type, so you cannot even write something like `Either<A extends C, B extends C, C>`. Clearly a shame, as your `Either` class would really be handy :)

Comment: and apparently javac 7 allows forward-reference, so `<A,B,C>` works too. (forward reference never forbidden by JLS)

Comment: it would definitely work, but defeat the purpose, as you would have to identify yourself the common supertype. That said, you _could_ infer the supertype and provide kind of the same functionality using a mix of generics and introspection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure A and B share a common ancestry.

```
public class Either<A extends CommonAncestor, B extends CommonAncestor> {
    public CommonAncestor get() {....}
}
```

or

```
public class Either<C, A extends C, B extends C> {
    public C get() {....}
}
```

Comment: You're points valid, I was think more along the lines of `C` been an interface or class, but the example is unclear in it's meaning :P