# Different policy for wild card and generic class/method declaration. Why?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, type-erasure

I have read a lot of information generics and I have knew a lot of new information. But I have some misunderstandings.

### Misunderstaning #1

I **can** write

```
class MyClass <T extends Number>{}
```

and I can write:

```
List<? super Number> list;
```

also I can write:

```
List<? extends Number> list;
```

But I **cannot** write

```
class MyClass <T super Number>{}
```

### Misunderstaning #2

I can write

```
class MyClass <T extends Number & Comparable>{}
```

But I cannot write

```
List<? extends Number & Comparable> list;
```

---

Can you explain why were these variants forbidden ?

**P.S.**
I have read related topic but I could not find answer there. I have read quotes from java docs but I don't understand the true cause

Comment: First, remember these are compile time checks due to [type-erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Second, I can only refer you to [JLS 5.1.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) and
[JLS 8.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2).

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I know it. I want to understand concept

Comment: Because a capture-of is different from a template type.

Comment: Is capture == wild card?

Comment: What is "wild card" in Java? Capture-of is the `?`. Template type is the `T`, but could also by `TYPE` or `FRED`.

Comment: *It's written Collection<?> (pronounced "collection of unknown"), that is, a collection whose element type matches anything. It's called a wildcard type for obvious reasons.* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I cannot find word "capture" at this Oracle tutorial

Comment: Good news! [JLS 4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

Comment: Hence "Is capture == wild card?" right answer true?

Comment: Concerning the first question: This is explained in detail in http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107

Answer (score 1):

Now, I can't say I can provide an authoritative answer on these, but (most of) these bounds make sense to me.

`T extends Number` works because no matter what `T` is, you have some set of guaranteed behavior/methods provided by your bounds -- in this case, it's guaranteed that `T` has some methods as defined by `Number`, so whenever you work with a `T` object you know that it supports some number of methods.

`? extends Number` works similarly to `T extends Number`, except you don't really care what `?` is because you never directly deal with those objects in your code, so it's OK if the precise type is "lost".

`? super Number` is OK because you're never really dealing with *exactly* what type the `?` represents, so the behavior of the `?` isn't really important. From what I know it's just used for consumers, where all you really care about is that the method/type can always deal with any object whose type goes up to the lower bound.

But `T super Number` is a bit of a pointless bound, because now you could deal with objects of type `T`, and the *only* behavior that can be guaranteed is that of *`Object`*, because `T` could be `Object`, `Serializable`, or `Number` -- and you don't really have any consistent set of behaviors for those types that the compiler can go off of. So it isn't allowed probably because it's added complexity for zero benefit.

(I used "behavior" rather loosely here, but I suppose it means something close to "available methods")

---

`T extends Number & Comparable`, again, is OK because you're working with `T` objects and the bounds provide guarantees as to how that `T` will behave.

Now, `? extends Number & Comparable` is a bit trickier. I can't say, intuitively, why this is disallowed. There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643241/why-cant-you-have-multiple-interfaces-in-a-bounded-wildcard-generic) answer (which I see you had difficulty understanding), which makes it seem to me that it's simply a limitation of Java. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230002/multiple-wildcard-bounds) answer also backs up the idea that it's a Java limitation more than a theoretical one.

So in the end, I suppose `? extends Number & Comparable` is the only disallowed bound that doesn't really make sense to me. Perhaps I'll be enlightened sometime later, at which point I'll try to remember to come back to update this. But at least as of now from what I've read it seems simply that it's a design decision/limitation.